# Which image is looks better resolultion (png or svg)

Tags: android-studio, uiimageasset

Which image is looks beeter resolultion (png or svg)

I have used but it not looks good for smaller icons

Comment: "If you're going to be using high quality images, detailed icons or need to preserve transparency, PNG is the winner. SVG is ideal for high quality images and can be scaled to ANY size." (found on the internet within 5mins of searching, so you have to be clearer when asking such a question)

Answer (score 2):

**Svg Image** because you can scale them to any size and you don't loss of quality.

**SVG** files basically use for logo, icons, etc.
So, I recommend you to use **SVG**

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends about the img type.

If You are dealing with an icon than go for SVG :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Image_types